# Homemade shampoo make my scalp too dry?

Tags: nutrition, dermatology, natural-remedy, hair, scalp

I've tried to make DIY shampoo but it dries my scalp too much(not dandruff).

My combo:

- 1 tsp almond oil
- 1 tsp virgin coconut oil
- 1 tsp raw honey
- 1 tsp vegetable glycerine
- a few drops of vitamin E
- 10 drops of essential oil

I just don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). I'm not sure whether this piece of information is relevant, but - what sort of essential oil do you use?

Comment: sometimes, I use essential oil, sometimes not. Here's the brand bought from amazon http://www.amazon.com/Therapeutic-Aromatherapy-Eucalyptus-Edens-Garden/dp/B002RSEPAY/ref=sr_1_1_s_it?s=hpc&ie=UTF8&qid=1459068251&sr=1-1&keywords=eden+gardens+essential+oils

Comment: I was referring to the plant the oil is extracted form, not the brand.. But if you use all six of these (eucalyptus, lavender, peppermint, sweet orange, lemon and tea tree) interchangeably and sometimes don't even use the essential oils then I'm lost since these were my only "suspects" in your formulation. Maybe someone else can crack this :-)

Comment: How do you know it's the shampoo? Have you switched shampoos and observed that your scalp is dry only when using the homemade one?

Comment: I've been using only like that for months, and not touched any other commercial brands in 1 year already. @lucky Yes sometimes i don't use essential oil but the result is the same, just don't know why oil could make my scalp that dry while all I read on the net, warm oil helps to cure the hair dryness.

Comment: I think I'll change the ingredients to my homegrown Aloe vera gel + oil + honey + vitamin E, C to see how it works.